Why does this LP38693SD-3.3 linear regulator not work?
I recently built a PCB that uses a LP38693SD-3.3 LDO to step down +5V to +3.3V. Today when I assembled all the components on the PCB I was surprised that the output of the LDO is +5V, the same as the input voltage, instead of +3.3V. After I encountered this problem, I thought that maybe the IC was not working properly, so I made sure I had the correct part and changed the component with another one. In the end, I got the same result. Also, I made sure the IC was correctly placed, with the dot on the package aligning with the first pin. I don't see where I have gone wrong. Any help is appreciated!
The link from the IC I bought: LP38693SDX-3.3/NOPB
The schematic of the LDO:

The layout of the LDO:

The layout of the LDO in real life:


Is your R9 any other value than 10 mohm per chance?

@winny I just checked to make sure, and yes, the resistor has a value of 0.01 ohms with a 1% tolerance, 200mW power rating and 100PPM (CFN0402AFX-R010ELF).

Which exact part you bought, what reads on the part, and is the SNS pin properly soldered, and is the part mounted in correct orientation instead of rotated 180 degrees? The schematics or PCB layout do not explain what you observe.

@Justme I bought the LP38693SDX-3.3/NOPB LDO from MOUSER ELECTRONICS. I put a link with the part from where I bought it in the original post. I am pretty sure the SNS is properly soldered, because I soldered and unsoldered the part many times, and it still wouldn't work. It reads "392HF L130B" on the IC. I added a photo with the layout of the LDO in real life.  The linear regulator is not rotated 180 degrees.

It should be the correct part in correct orientation. The soldering does not look very good. All those solder blobs floating around. Are you sure the regulator is the source of the problem, instead of solder bridge somewhere else, or under the chip? Also are you sure the chip is not damaged by the soldering? Or is the PCB manufactured OK or could it have shorts or other errors?

Soldering looks very suspect - I would imagine there is an unconnected pad somewhere, or a short circuit given all the little blobs of solder around the place.

@Justme I am sure this IC is the problem, because I used a digital multimeter to check the voltages, and when I connected the measuring device to GND and T_OUT I got almost +5V on the dot, when I try to see the voltage on the other side of the IC it shows 0. I used soldering paste and a heat gun to solder the IC, but I always pointed the heat gun from below the PCB on the other side, so I don't think the part is damaged.  I agree, the solder is horrible, it is my first time doing it, but I don't think this is the problem, since as I said, the current suddenly stops while going through the IC.

@TomCarpenter in this case I think I will try to clean the PCB a little bit and resolder the IC to make sure every pin is soldered and there are no short circuits.

@Robert I don't follow: In your question you said you have 5V on input and 3.3V output, but now you say you measure 0V on output?

All those solder balls make me think you may have a short from the EP to the output.

@Justme sorry for the mistake. To clarify, when I connect the digital multimeter to T_OUT and GND, the measuring device indicates +5V on the dot. When I connect the device to the +3.3V, the multimeter measure +5V also.

@vir you are right, it is a possibility that I have a short circuit under the LDO.  These WSON-6 packages are pretty hard to solder, I have to admit.

@Robert Did you use a stencil? Flux? Hot air, or a reflow oven? A DFN with a pitch as large as that shouldn't be too difficult to solder, unless you're trying to do it with a soldering iron or a paint-stripping heat gun or something.

@Robert You probably have a short between input and output. Try and measure continuity between C15 pad1 and C16 pad1. Otherwise you might have damaged the IC during soldering. You can do that even when the heat gun is pointed from below the PCB, some ICs are just less resistant to overheating and are harder to solder with uncontrolled conditions.
